# How to write to Excel in Python without installing modules?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, raspberry-pi, pip

I try to write to an Excel file in Python, but unfortunally you need to install xlwt oder Pandas to get this done. Now, the problem is, that i wanna use this on a Raspberry Pi, which is not connected to internet. So that means, I cannot install these packages.

Is there still a way how to do it

Comment: Can you connect a flash drive to it? If so then you can download the modules and transfer them to the pi

Comment: i can connect usb stick and hard disk

Comment: Have you considered writing to `csv` or `json` file types instead? They probably would be better options for interchangeability.

Comment: Yes, i think csv might be the best option

Comment: as @BernardL told CSV will be go to options without a problem, let me know in case you need any help.